# SQL SERVER 2008 Max Constant Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi all i need help Again :D

it goes like this i need to find max constant value or max counted value for example i have

```
ClientID   YEAR      МОNTH
1          2013        1    
1          2013        2  
1          2013        3 
1          2013        4  
1          2013        5  
1          2013        6  
1          2013        7  
1          2013        8  
1          2013        9  
1          2013       10  
1          2013       11  
1          2013       12  
2          2013        1    
2          2013        2  
2          2013        3 
2          2013        4    
2          2013        6  
2          2013        7  
2          2013        8   
2          2013       10  
2          2013       11  
2          2013       12
```

if i do

```
select clientID,year, max(month) from table where client id =1

select clientID,year, max(month) from table where client id =2
```

then i get

```
ClientID   YEAR      МОNTH
    1      2013        12
    2      2013        12
```

is there i way to select until the first missing month? Like

```
ClientID   YEAR      МОNTH
    1      2013        12
    2      2013        4
```

TNX in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT ClientID, YEAR, MIN(MONTH)
FROM table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
    FROM table c 
    WHERE c.MONTH = table.MONTH + 1 
        AND c.ClientID = table.ClientID
        AND c.YEAR = table.YEAR)
GROUP BY ClientID, YEAR
```

That looks for all entries that are just before a gap, then takes the minimum one for any combination of `ClientID` and `YEAR` that has more than one result.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab635/2)

Comment: nope its not working. Now even if a client is missing month 12 im still getting the 12 at the and

Comment: @Delete It works for me with all of the information you've given in the question, as evidenced by the SQLFiddle I've linked to.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that on the same klient_id there are records from 2009-2013

Comment: @Delete Oh, yes, that would do it! Edited to check the YEAR as well in the subquery, I think that should fix it.

Comment: Oh i get it now this one is selecting the last missing month on every year. I need it to select the first missing month -1 of every year. That why i was getting 12 month every almost everywhere its not 12/2013 still. :D

Comment: Oh damn man im sorry it was my bad. This works perfect i needed plus 1 check that i did not specify in the post that was payed=1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select clientid,year,max(month) from [dbo].[24] where id <(


SELECT TOP 1 t1.month+1 
FROM [dbo].[24] t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[24] t2 WHERE t2.month = t1.month + 1)
ORDER BY t1.month
)

group by clientid,year
```

Comment: im not getting anything. all empty